# Library ClassNotFound

Tags: android, analytics

I have a library, I marked as IsLibrary in the project properties. This library only have a class, no layout or activity.
This library only have functions to work with Google Analytics and I add the library of Google Analytics.

I created another project and I used this library. In this project I put the permission necessary to Google Analytics (internet....) but I receive an error of ClassNotFound.

I tried too to make a jar to used independently but I have the same error.

Thank you.

Comment: the project reference this library need use 'right click your project - properties - android - select add and choose the library'

Comment: Yes I do it, but sometimes I receive that error. I haven't write nothing in the manifest, is it necessary?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't just put the library in the build path, but you select it as a library project in the 'android' section of your project's properties. Also, if you are building via ant, you need to run 'android update project' once more.

Comment: Yes, is a library project. I try too with a jar but I receive the same error unless I add the Analytics library in both projects. I don't understand 'if you are building via ant you need to run 'android update project' once more'

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the box opposite the jar in Project > Properties > Java Nuild Path > Order and Export? That determines whether the jar actually gets copied to your apk file. It is not set by default.

Comment: I put the Analytics library and I marked the Order and export option. Yes. In the project that used the library only I add it as a library